# Error performing the action getAttachments on CFExchangemail

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, coldfusion-9

I am trying to get attachments using the `CFExchangemail` tag but I am getting this error:

```
Error performing the action.

Exchange error Code : 501.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion9/wwwroot/ExcgangeCode/read.cfm: line 229
227 :                     uid="#GetData.uid#" 
228 :                     name="attachData" 
229 :                     attachmentPath="C:\test\#i#"
230 :                     generateUniqueFilenames="yes">
231 :
```

Here is my code:

```
<cfif GetData.HasAttachment>                    
    <cfexchangemail action="getAttachments" 
                    connection="conn1" 
                    uid="#GetData.uid#" 
                    name="attachData" 
                    attachmentPath="C:\test\1"
                    generateUniqueFilenames="yes">
</cfif>
```

The folder `C:\test\1` is created successfully but attachments are not saved in that location. It is saying `Error performing the action.Exchange error Code : 501`. Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using?  There was a [bug with ColdFusion 9 and Exchange 2007](http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/83574#).  There was also some [discussion about this issue on the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/752503).  I am also not sure if ColdFusion 9 supports Exchange 2010 [from this Ben Forta blog](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/5/11/ColdFusion-And-Exchange-2010). But I guess your connection is working just not getting/saving attachments.

Comment: yes, connection is working properly and is giving attachment file name, but the problem is with getting attachment and save it to directory. i have coldfusion 9, should it will work with coldfusion10?

Comment: So are you using Exchange 2007?  Not sure if it will work in ColdFusion 10 or not.  I don't see any bugs listed for ColdFusion 10.  I found [this bug for ColdFusion 9 that was supposedly fixed in 2009](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3039380). But then I also found [this bug listed for ColdFusion 9 in 2010 that was not fixed](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3041764).

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the version of Exchange that you are using. There was some pretty good discussion about this issue on the Adobe Forums (with no resolution). [CFExchange and Attachment Issue.](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/752503)

Unfortunately I think you may be running into a bug that was never resolved for ColdFusion 9. I have found the following bugs for ColdFusion 9 and Exchange 2007.

- [Bug 83574 (CFExchange)](http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/83574) Attempting to login to an Exchange 2007 server and retrieve attachments from messages. I connect to the Exchange server, but when I attempt to get attachments, Exchange responds with a 501 error.
   *This bug is listed under the old tracking system. I also found it under the new tracking system (see below) and still not resolved.*
- [ColdFusion 9.0  -  Bug 3039380](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3039380) Bug 78957: then i am using the cfexchangemail getAttachmentsand adds the attachmentPath="C:\temp" i get the error 501 and i can not find out where it came form.
   *This bug is listed as fixed.*
- [ColdFusion 9.0  -  Bug 3041764](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3041764) Bug 83574: Attempting to login to an Exchange 2007 server and retrieve attachments from messages.
   *This bug is listed as cannot reproduce but you can see several comments from user saying they have the same problem.*

Also found a blog by Ben Forta mentioning that the `<cfexchange>` tag in ColdFusion 9 does not support Exchange 2010 (posted in May 2011).

> ColdFusion features a `<cfexchange>` tag that can be used to access and manipulate Microsoft Exchange calendar data, contacts, and more. This tag was introduced in ColdFusion 8, and supports the versions of Exchange available back then. The tag does not support Exchange 2010, much to the dismay of many users. And while I can't provide dates yet, I can confirm that the next version of ColdFusion will indeed update `<cfexchange>` so that it supports Exchange 2010.

This may have been fixed in ColdFusion 10. I cannot test this theory but I have not found any bugs listed for it under ColdFusion 10.

Comment: i have CF10 and Exchange Server version 10, i am still getting error code 501 server saying "Error performing the action". what to do?

Comment: Your question was tagged with ColdFusion 9. If you are running ColdFusion 10 and Exchange Server 2010 then the information that I provided does not apply to you.